# Один FragmentViewPager в другом

Tags: android, android-viewpager

Есть программа, главный экран которой компонуется из FragmentPagerAdapter для перелистывания двух фрагментов между собой. Один из фрагментов на главном экране содержит еще один FragmentPagerAdapter, но уже с другими тремя фрагментами. При запуске программы второй PagerAdapter рисуется не правильно, а именно висит в воздухе и не наполняется данными. Как я понял, есть ограничения на мое желание "засунуть один ViewPager в другой". Как ужить эти фрагменты между собой и добиться правильной работы?

Comment: Пробовали во второй адаптер вместо `getFragmentManager()` передавать `getChildFragmentManager()`?

Comment: Крайне плохая концепция у вас. Вы думали о том, как пользователь будет знать, где ему тыркать пальцем, чтобы листалось нужное? А то он захочет листануть между 2 фрагментами на верхнем уровне, а будут листаться фрагменты во вложенном. Ваш вариант реализуем, но лучше сделать скролл чего-то одного, а другой пусть переключается по нажатиям на Tab-ы